# Why did Rangers release Marvin Andrews at the end of the 2005-06 season?

Tags: football

[Marvin Andrews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_Andrews), the Trinidad and Tobago footballer famous for having a "miracle" and "healing" his left knee ligament with "the force of God", was elected player of the year by Rangers in the 2004-05 season. However, he was subsequently released as a free agent in the 2005-06 season. What happened?

My guess is that, although he could sustain a few matches with his damaged knee, in the end it was simply too much without proper scientific treatment and he couldn't return to his previous standard of playing anymore. But I couldn't find any explanation of exactly what happened.

Comment: I was reading about him on the Guardian this week, he sounds like his body was absolutely knackered, I don't have an official source to say that was the reason why they released him but it makes sense based on what I read.

Comment: Yeah this is also what I think after reading the Guardian article, and it's therefore I would like a definitive explanation from one who kept an eye on Rangers that season.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have read and heard he was released because his knee made him a liability. On this [forum](http://www.cpfc.org/forums/archive/index.php/t-139272.html) the fans talk about it said that Paule Le Guen deemed he was surplus to requirements at Rangers and that Andrews was afraid to take a medical at Reading in case he failed it as it would look bad when he was trying to find a new club. I didn't see any interview where he gave a reason behind his release but the amount of injuries he suffered must have made up Rangers' mind about releasing him in 2006.